# Java MessageFormat - best way to check incomplete format

Tags: java, messageformat

```
String[] params = new String[];
params[0] = "param0";

String pattern = "{2}, {1}, {0}"

String result = MessageFormat.format(pattern, params);

System.out.println(result);
```

Result:

```
{2}, {1}, param0
```

I want to throw an exception if the size of `params` array does not much the number of placeholders in `pattern`. What would be the best way to validate this?

```
MessageFormat format = new MessageFormat(pattern);
if (format.getFormats().length != params.size()) {
  throw new Exception("example");
}
```

Comment: `format.getFormats().length != params.size()` - that is definitely wrong, for example format `{0}{0}`  requires `1` parameter, but `#getFormats().length` returns `2`

Comment: `#getFormatsByArgumentIndex()` method seems to be more reliable